# How can I delete all my direct messages at once in Twitter?

Tags: twitter, twitter-direct-message

How do I delete all my Twitter direct messages in one go without having to click the delete button for each message?

---

The Twitter help article [About direct messages](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/direct-messages#basics), as of February 26, 2023 says the following about deleting direct messages (only bullet list applied, bold, inline images, etc. not included) :

> To delete a Direct Message or conversation:
>
> - To delete a Direct Message, click on the message and select Delete.
> - To leave a conversation, locate the conversation and click to open it. Click the information  icon, and select Leave conversation.
> - When you delete a Direct Message or leave a conversation (sent or received), it is deleted from your account only. Others in the conversation will still be able to see Direct Messages or conversations that you have deleted.

As of February 26, 2023, searching  `bulk delete direct messages` in the Twitter Help Center, only returned one result [Automation rules](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation) (quoted pasted as plain text)

> Updated November 3, 2017
>
> This page is primarily intended for developers.

There above doesn't help as there is any guidance for end users about how to do this task.

Comment: "the decline of interested on the Twitter web app over the year." is not a close reason.