# Erasing all tweets from a Twitter account

Tags: twitter

I've been asked to take care of a Twitter account. And now I've got to erase all of over 3,000 tweets. And I've been looking for tools that might help me out with this bulk/mass erase of tweets. Nothing works. I tried [TwitWipe](http://www.twitwipe.com/), and it doesn't work.

How can I wipe out all the tweets from this Twitter account using a program that I can run from my computer?

The usage of a new account was discussed, but I have to use this one. The bottom line is: I have to erase this, and I 'm not planning on spending an entire day clicking repeatedly one tweet at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I found [TwitWipe](http://www.twitwipe.com/), though I have no direct experience with it.

For what it's worth, I found the same question was asked over at (yet another) Stack Exchange site, [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/how-can-i-delete-all-my-direct-messages-at-once-in-twitter).

Answer (score 1):

[Delete All My Tweets](http://www.deleteallmytweets.com) is another option for those looking to easily delete all their tweets.

> Delete All My Tweets is an app which does what it says on the tin. If you want to delete all tweets from your Twitter account simply sign in with Twitter, autorise the app, click to confirm and sit back as up to 1000 tweets are deleted in one go. If you need to delete more simply repeat the process.

Answer (score 1):

**[TweetDelete](http://www.tweetdelete.net/)** allows you to delete all of your tweets.

It also has a nifty feature of *automatically* deleting tweets older that a specified age:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Twitter accounts can be renamed, so you might be able to rename it, then create a new one with the name you want.

Or, you set up another account, rename the "target" account to something else, then rename the new one to the target name.

Comment: While this would be OK for new followers, any existing followers will be left following the renamed account.